# Can I use the SD Card with which I have installed OS as an external storage device ?? If yes, is the stack for it inbuilt?

Tags: sd-card

Do I need to unmount the OS SD card and mount a new one or will the same SD Card can be used further for storage of data purpose?? Kindly provide me with the details of stack (whether it is inbuilt or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SD card in a Pi is the equivalent of the hard disk in a PC.

The SD card contains two partitions

1. a partition with the files needed for boot formatted as FAT (so it's readable from a PC)
2. a partition used to store the operating system and application programs **and any files you create**.  This is formatted as ext4 which is not readable by a Windows PC (although you can get add on software which will read/write ext4 format).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one more doubt, you dont require any kernel to access the SD Card?? for eg. I am writing C code for processing and storing the data in SD Card (in Raspbian OS), just the directory path of SD Card is enough for me to store data? (as in shell script)

Comment: Raspbian OS includes the kernel.  The Linux kernel will be in memory and running when your C program is running.  The Linux kernel will handle filesystem requests to the SD card just as it would any other storage device.

Comment: I have installed "2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie" and it is working fine in the terminal window. (I am using windows os) . All I need is a desktop environment for the raspbian OS. Kindly explain in detail as I am new to this